# Tailwind colors doesnt display when changed

Tags: arrays, reactjs, tailwind-css, background-color, array-map

i  got an array with colors already defined in the tailwind default color palette , as follows

```
colors: ["red-600", "blue-600", "pink-600", "black", "white", "yellow-600"]
```

I mapped over the array to produce small boxes with a background color thats defined in the array.

```
{colors.map((col, i) => (
        <button
          className="cursor-pointer"
          key={i}
        >
          <div
            className={`mt-3 border-2 border-solid border-black bg-${col} w-8 h-8`}
          >
```

[image]

my issue is if i change any of the colors in the array ( like changing red-600 to red-900) it doesnt display despite that both colors are defined in the default color palette

[image]

what could possibility be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I at one point had this issue while attempting something very similar to what you're currently trying... I realized that you can't set a Tailwind value partially as a variable, rather it must be the entire value if you're going to use a variable for it.

**Example:**

> make an array strictly for `bg-colors`

```
bgColors: [
  "bg-red-600",
  "bg-blue-600", 
  "bg-pink-600", 
  "bg-black", 
  "bg-white", 
  "bg-yellow-600"
]
```

> and now you should be able to use them as variables with the whole value instead of a partial value.

```
className={`${col}`} // ${col} === bg-color-###
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you should set colors array as a `state`, that thing make this component will re-render when this array change.

**Second**, if only order inside `colors array` change, it don't force this component re-render to read your state change, so you should add another state to force component re-render like `[forceChangeColor, setForceChangeColor] = useState(0)`:

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState(["red-600", "blue-600", "pink-600", "black", "white", "yellow-600"])
const [forceChangeColor, setForceChangeColor] = useState(0)

const handleChangeColor = () => {
  setColors([/*set your change colors*/]) // <=== set Colors change in here
  setForceChangeColor(prev => prev + 1) //<=== Make another state change to force this component re-render to re-read colors state
}


{colors.map((col, i) => (
        <button
          className="cursor-pointer"
          key={i}
        >
          <div
            className={`mt-3 border-2 border-solid border-black bg-${col} w-8 h-8`}
          >
```